# Pandas time series operations

Tags: python, scipy, pandas, time-series

I'm new to Pandas. I have a time series data. How could I do the following operations easily?

I have a 2d matrix called input. Each row has 5 elements. There's lots of rows (thousands)

`input[t,:] = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]`

(1) I need to calculate the relative difference between samples.

i.e. `rel[t,:] = ( input[t,:]-input[t-1,:] ) / input[t-1,:]`

(2) I need to create a sliding window of size 80.

i.e. `win[t,:] = [rel[t,:],rel[t-1,:],...,rel[t-79,:]]`

How could I do this in Pandas, or any other framework, such as scikit.timeseries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both in plain numpy, although pandas will probably have specific functionality that makes it easier. But:

```
rel = np.diff(input) / input[:-1]
```

and

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
win = as_strided(rel, shape=(rel.shape[0]-79, 80), strides=rel.strides*2)
```

will do it.

---

If the input has more than one row, you can still do the above as:

```
rel = np.diff(input, axis=1) / input[:, :-1]
win = as_strided(rel, shape=(rel.shape[0], rel.shape[1]-79, 80),
                 strides=rel.strides + rel.strides[1:])
```

although you may want to play around with the 'shape' and matching `strides` to get the exact windowed shape you are after.

Comment: what if input has `k` dimensions?

Comment: @siamii How exactly would you like to calculate relative differences or window the k-dimensional data? It can certainly be done, but you need to define what exactly you want done.

Comment: I meant that input has k columns. So instead of 1 element per row, there's k elements per row. each row represents a time step. My data is 2d matrix. I update the question

Comment: Thanks but I think I didn't explain clearly enough. Your original answer was good, it's that each element has k features. I need to calculate the differences and windows between timestep. I think your follwup answer calculates the differences between the features horizontally, instead of between the timesteps vertically. right? Probably all you need to change in your original answer is `shape=(rel.shape[0]-79, 80*k)`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The docs are quite comprehensive on these types of operations

see:

1) http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-series-related-instance-methods

2) http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#expanding-window-moment-functions